# Unable to parse JSON in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Please help me out with my code. Am trying to populate the table in html with the getJSON. Am getting alert which is inside of getJSON but not the one which is inside of $.each(jso,function(i,j). Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>#{name}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />

    <script src="js/cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/database.js"></script>

    <script src="js/FileAPI.js"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>

    <script src="js/filesystem.js"></script>
    <script src="js/listutils.js"></script>
    <style>

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div data-role="page" data-overlay-theme="d">
            <div data-role="header" class="ui-bar-b">
                <a onclick="onBackKeyDown();" data-icon="back" id="back">Back</a>
                <h1 id="header">Outlet Visit Report</h1>
                <a onclick="onUploadPhoto();" data-icon="check" id="send">Send</a>

        </div>


                <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <table id="myTable"> 
                <th>Item Code</th>
                <th>Item Description</th>
                <th>MRP</th>
                <th>Initial Quantity</th>
                <th>Current Quantity</th>
                <th>Refill Quantity</th>
                <th>Out of Stock</th>

                </table>


                <div style="display: none">
                        <input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="data" id="data" />

                </div>
                </form>

                <a data-transition="pop" id="busypop" style="display: none"
                    href="#positionWindow" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window">
                </a>
                <div data-role="popup" id="positionWindow" data-dismissable="false"
                    data-theme="d" data-tolerance="15,15" class="ui-content"
                    data-position-to="window">

                    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="b"
                        data-inset="true">

                        <li data-role="list-divider">Update Status</li>
                        <li data-role="fieldcontain">

                            <p>Please wait.Upload is in Progress........</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>


                </div>




            <div data-role="popup" id="popupMap" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="a" data-corners="false" data-tolerance="15,15">

                <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>

                <iframe id="imframe" src=""  seamless></iframe>

            </div>

            <a id="opM" href="#popupMap" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window"  data-theme="b" data-inline="true"></a>


        </div>

        <script>

        var user = "KBM";
        var base="";


        $(document).ready(function(){

        window.onload = devideReady();

            fetchData();    


        });


        function devideReady(){
            document.addEventListener("backbutton", function(){
                $("#back").click();
            }, false);
            initDatabase();
            readProperty(function(data){
                if(data!=null){
                    user = data['user'];
                }

            });
        }
        document.addEventListener("deviceready",devideReady, true);
        function getUser() {
            if(!isMobile.any()){
                return "admin";
            }
            return user;
        }
        var backHtml="";

        function onBackKeyDown() {
            window.open('mainpage.html',"_self");
        }

        function fetchData(){
        alert("before getJSON");
    $.getJSON("http://appkbm.appspot.com/jsp/index.jsp?action=json&user="+user+"&name=Item",function(jso){
            alert("After the query");
            var arr = new Array();
            $.each(jso,function(i,j){
            alert("Inside the Loop");
            var obj = (jQuery.parseJSON(j.data))[0];
            arr.push(obj);
            });

            $.each(arr,function(i,j){
                $("#table").append("<tr><td><input type="hidden" name="itemCode" id="itemCode" value ="+j['ITEM CODE']+" /></td><td><input type="text" name="itemDescription" id="itemDescription" value ="+j['ITEM DESCRIPTION']+" /></td><td><input type="text" name="mrp" id="mrp" value ="+j['SKU MRP']+" /></td><td><input type="text" name="initialQuant" id="initialQuant" /></td><td><input type="text" name="currentQuant" id="currentQuant" /></td><td><input type="text" name="refillQuant" id="refillQuant" /></td><td><input type="text" name="outOfStock" id="outOfStock" /></td></tr>");
                });
    });
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why would you call `$.parseJSON` on each of the `jso[i].data` objects? Or are they really strings? You should not have JSON strings inside JSON. Show us how the server response looks like!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include *A* only relevant code (by posting more then just the relevant code, it makes it harder to answer the questions, and less people will take the time to do so), *B* include all relevant parts to answer the question (which in this case would be to include the JSON you are trying to decode).

Comment: Try console.log(jso); before the .each and see if you're getting anything back.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete question. And thank you all for the reply. Here is my db data looks like.                                  [{"ITEM CODE":"SF560R02","ITEM DESCRIPTION":"Strawberry Corn Flakes 575g x 12 Mrp Rs. 229","GL PROD LINE":"SF56","INVENTORY CLASS":"STRAW-CF","PRODUCT CATEGORY":"RTEC","PRODUCT PORTFOLIO":"All Family","Pack Grammage":"575","CARTON COUNT":"12","SKU MRP":"229"}] So that's why am doing $.parseJSON on each on the jso[i].data. Please Help. Thanks in advance....